# Open (residential) less safe than Public WiFi?

Tags: encryption, wifi

I connect to WiFi at coffee shops using VPN regularly but I'm apprehensive to join a random open network (ex. "CARRIER47393") in a residential area. Should I avoid using it (even with VPN)?

My concern is that a hacker could set up a free network, allowing greater access to data (because they have full control of the entire network "admin") vs hacker accessing the network remotely at a coffee shop ("user").

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you would somehow (with VPN) trust a network named similar to a coffee shop even if you don't know if this really from the coffee shop but you would less trust a network with some unrelated name. But, wouldn't you expect that a smart hacker  does a bit of social engineering and will make his network sound more appealing? This would mean that you should trust a network with a seemingly trustable name even less :)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich 1) assume I'm positive correct network 2) regular name + no password = suspect. Savvy enough to change name but not pass?

Answer (score 4):

Open wifi is open wifi, whether is is residential or not.  A MITM can be performed on a coffee shop network just the same as it could be done on a residential network, albeit using different means.

There is no higher or lower level of security between a coffee shop's wifi and a residential wifi.

Comment: The difference is that the hacker has direct access to the network, and that's the essence of my question

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by direct access to the network?  The attacker can be directly connected to the network in either scenario.

Comment: I mean that they have complete control: access point, router, etc could configure the network however they want. For example I'm under the impression that corporations are able to monitor everything their employees do so clearly there's some kind of control a network admin can have that would be harder for a stranger to obtain

Comment: Assume that a hacker set up the residential network and that another hacker (of equal ability) is a user of the coffee shop network

Comment: @JBallin How do you know that what you believe to be the access point of a coffee shop isn't actually an [evil twin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_twin_(wireless_networks)) set up by a hacker? Or that a hacker has infiltrated the coffee shop and compromised their wifi network?

Comment: The problem with this evil twin stuff is that it is so boring. Interesting stuff has SSL and HTTPS pinning now. Interesting stuff sends a SMS if a new device logs in. At most you can get a few antique POP3 accounts, some metadata, and do session hijacking. The most cool thing I have seen with this attack involves squid and javascript injection, and of course WPAD is always funny.

Comment: @Philipp assume isn't evil twin. Can't you have more control with direct access to the hardware?